# All tasks are blocked from ContinueWith [C#].. while calling Task.Delay waiting a value that should be changed by other tasks

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, task

```cs
string VariableA
string VariableB
string VariableC

void Main(){
   run((string result){A= result;});
   run((string result){B = result;});
   run((string result){C = result;});

   Task.Run(async ()=>{
            while (A == null)
                 await Task.delay(100);
            })
            ... unreachable code
            ... when breaking here >> t.Result holds a value but the owner task is Blocked in task window
}

void run(Action<string> action){
    Task.Run( async ()=>{ Some Operations; } )
    .ContinueWith((t, o) => {
                             Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
                                                         action(t.Result);
                                                                  }) ; 
                             }, SynchronizationContext.Current);
}
```

> It takes for ever .. and once I debug.. I found the task results were retrieved but couldn't be Passed through the continuation action .. which feeds the while loop for ever

.

> SynchronizationContext.Current is used on ContinueWith

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can add a minimal example of your code to your question.

Comment: All i can take away from your explanation is that it is too vague to give an accurate picture of what your code looks like and is doing. Look into improving your question by **editing** it and adding a [mcve].

Comment: I hope you consider the code here

Comment: Just for testing: What if your `run` method explicitly sets the string field `A` (or whatever it is being called in reality) to a non-null value directly and synchronously (not within a task). Will `while (A == null)` then still be stuck?

Comment: I've just tested this>> added ```A = Result``` inside the async task.run and then shows a ```messagebox```.. 

.. it shows one single instance of the message not three .. and the whole application is irresposive
and stuck in the while loop

Comment: Are you just waiting for A to finish, or for all of them to finish? Rather than polling, can't you have the Run method return a task, add it into an array and then use task.whenall?

Comment: Take a look at [Capitalization Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions). `run` is against the rules. The correct is `Run`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling Run `Initializing the tasks` from within the constructor was the crime comitted..

Just by moving it to the constuctor of the Control .. it was solved!

Comment: Your code has multiple problems. You'd better scrap it and restart from scratch, otherwise other problems will emerge and bite you sooner or later.